# How to set variable values for different statement for same NOT FOUND SQL EXCEPTION in STORE PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I Have A Procedure Where I need to set d_x FOR select statement 1, d_y FOR select statement 2, d_z for select statement 3. How could i modify below procedure to achieve that ...

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE A () 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE d_a INT;
        DECLARE d_b INT;
        DECLARE d_c INT;
        ---
        --
        -
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        BEGIN
            SET d_x = 1;
            SET d_y = 2;
            SET d_z = 3;
        END;

        SELECT aa INTO d_x FROM TEST1;
        SELECT bb INTO d_y FROM TEST2;
        SELECT cc INTO d_z FROM TEST3;
    END
```

Comment: One solution in my mind is now to create sub procedures to achieve this. Could It possible to achieve in a single procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found One Solution for My Problem. And Probable Answer. But If there any more alternative ways please define.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A () 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE d_a INT;
        DECLARE d_b INT;
        DECLARE d_c INT;
        ---
        --
        -

      BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        BEGIN
            SET d_x = 1;
        END;
        SELECT aa INTO d_x FROM TEST1;
      END;
      BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        BEGIN
            SET d_y = 2;
        END;
        SELECT bb INTO d_y FROM TEST2;
      END;
            BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        BEGIN
            SET d_y = 2;
        END;
        SELECT cc INTO d_z FROM TEST3;
      END; 
    END
```